# Difference between Android SipAudioCall and Android Telecom Call

Tags: android, sip, telecommunication

I want to create an Android application which uses the SIP protocol.

I found the docs for the SIP implementation in Android:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html

My question is what exactly is the difference between this package and `Telecom` package which also got a `Call` object? When do I use one and when should I use the other?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/package-summary.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an app that want to register and run a SIP calling account but doesn't want to implement all of SIP, then you would use the SIP apis.

If you are a Dialer app that wants to replace the InCall UI (supported as of Android Marshmallow), you would implement android.telecom.InCallService.  Your app would be called on that service when there is a call (android.telecom.Call) for which to display UI.